# How to size an electricity accumulator

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

My electricity supplier offers the customer 3 hours of free energy per day at a maximum power of 3kW.

My daily energy requirement does not exceed 4kWh and hence my question:
Considering that I can have 9kW free every day, how can I size the batteries to be able to accumulate 9kW in less than 3 hours?

What type of batteries is the most suitable for my purpose?

Comment: Just an observation... how is it free if it costs 10 Euros per month?

Comment: the 10 euros are the fixed costs imposed by my electricity supplier..

Comment: Your units don't make sense - kWh is a measure of energy, not power. You don't get 9kWh by multiplying 3 hours by 3kWh, you get 9kWh by multiplying 3 hours by 3kW (not kWh). If your supplier is giving you 3kWh "free" per month then it makes no difference if you use that energy in 3 minutes, 3 hours or 3 days - you still only get 3kWh (not 9kWh).

Comment: @brhans I corrected my question.

Comment: You've fixed some units and broken others. If you really do get 3kW for 3 hours, then you can accumulate 9kWh (not 9kW). As for sizing the batteries - you'll typically see their capacity rated in Ah. So multiply that by the nominal battery voltage for a result in Wh. So how many of those batteries do you need to store 9kWh? Divide 9000Wh by  the battery capacity you calculated.

Comment: ok!!!!!!!!!! :)

Comment: Buy an electric car and charge it when power is free. Won't save you any electricity but it will save you a lot of gasoline, and gasoline is way more expensive than electricity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your daily requirement is for 4 kWh, it sounds like you need store only 4 kWh, not 9, as you can top up every day.

Starting with something tractable, consider lead acid car batteries, perhaps a 40 Ah 12 V one. That stores 40*12 = 480 Wh. You would on the face of it need 8 such batteries.

Lead acid quickly loses capacity when cycled to deeper than 50% discharge, so you would need 16 for the battery bank to have a long cycle life with a useable 4 kWh capacity.

This difference in useable and nominal capacity means that you could treat the second 4 kWh as emergency reserve, to use if your requirement one day was suddenly higher. However, being connected to the grid, you should compare the cost of providing for 'emergency' power by buying it from the company, or reducing the cycle life of your batteries with a deeper discharge.

As you have 3 hours to draw the 4 kWh to charge them, that's a power of 1333 W, which divided between 16 batteries is a power of 83 watts = 7 amps per battery, a very reasonable charging figure.

Sixteen lead acid batteries new is quite an investment, and they are fairly bulky. What might work better is a worn-out EV battery pack. Their new capacity is typically in the high 10s or just over 100 kWh, so a discarded one of those should meet your modest 4 kWh with no trouble at all, if you can get your hands on one cheaply.

You can work through similar sums for any other battery technology.

If you increased the size of the battery bank to a usable 9 kWh, you could sell the 'spare' 5 kWh that you don't use daily to a neighbour, or to charge an EV.

However, frame challenge, it's worth looking at tomnexus' answer to compare the real cost of stored electricity versus that supplied on tap at the time you want it from the power company. I would not be surprised if the only way to have this make economic sense was the use of 'free' batteries, so discarded 12 V lead acid from cars (with probably 50% of the name-plate capacity left, these will be free from recycling yards, you'll need plenty of space for them all) or discarded EV sleds (which may not be totally free as people are starting to get wise to using them for your specific purpose).

Answer (score 3):

Energy stored and then withdrawn from batteries *is not free*! In the case of lead-acid batteries, it is actually *much more expensive* than the same energy made with a diesel generator.

Some figures for you:

- Battery cost per kWh:  $ 250 ([AGM deep cycle](https://www.canbat.com/product/12v-100ah-deep-cycle-battery-agm/), retail, 10 kWh pack)
- Total lifetime energy storage/production per kWh of pack:  350 kWh (700 cycles to 50% discharge)
- Cost *just for the batteries you're burning up*: $ 0.71 / kWh

Compare that to your local power company... and to Diesel:

- Cost of diesel: $ 3.80 / gallon = $1.16/kg
- Conversion efficiency: 220 g / kWh
- Fuel cost of electricity: $ 0.25 / kWh

So the *wear and tear* on the lead acid battery is three times the price of the *fuel cost* of a diesel generator. Batteries are for special purposes only, where there is no utility, and where a generator is not appropriate (instant availability for UPS, small applications where generator capital cost is a problem, etc). They are a terrible way of storing *money*.

Lithium batteries are much better at this, but at home scale, probably not cheaper than your power company.